# cmake assembly: /usr/bin/ld: no input files

Tags: assembly, cmake, linker-scripts

I'm trying to familiarize myself with `cmake` and I've chosen a very simple hobby kernel written in assembly as a test-bed. The problem is, it seems like the linker is called prior to compiling the sources, I'm getting this error:

```
$ make
[100%] Linking ASM-ATT executable kernel
/usr/bin/ld: no input files
CMakeFiles/kernel.dir/build.make:69: recipe for target 'kernel' failed
make[2]: *** [kernel] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/kernel.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/kernel.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here's the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(kernel ASM-ATT)

enable_language(ASM-ATT)

set(CMAKE_ASM-ATT-COMPILER as)

set(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/linker.ld)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-N -T${LINKER_SCRIPT}")

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    multiboot.S
    start.S
    )

set_target_properties(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    LINK_DEPENDS "${LINKER_SCRIPT}"
    LINKER_LANGUAGE ASM-ATT
    )
```

I assume there's something obvious I'm missing here. What's the proper way to build assembly with a custom linker script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CMake, error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: no input files
```

usually means that CMake doesn't recongnize any file, passed to `add_executable`/`add_library` command, as **source file**.

In the given case `.S` files are not treated by CMake as assembler files for ASM-ATT language. [Wiki page](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Assembler#ASM-ATT), which describes assembling with CMAKE, explicitely states that:

> .S files, i.e. assembler files which require preprocessing, are not supported

If your assembler files are not required preprocessing, you may rename them to `.s` or `.asm` files, so CMake will treat them as source files for given language.